# When joining, is there a difference when you add the conditions in the join clause or the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a join like:

```
select u1.*
from users u
  inner join users u2 on u.id = u2.id
where u2.location = 'blah' and u2.level > 2
```

versus

```
select u1.*
from users u
  inner join users u2 on u.id = u2.id and u2.location='blah' and u2.level > 2
```

Can someone explain to me the differences and nuances of each query (assuming there is some kind of a differenc)

Comment: There is absolutely no difference on an `inner join`.

Comment: In most cases no. Maybe some execution plan/performance nuances

Comment: Like the others have said, more often not, no. Personally, I prefer to put literals in the `WHERE`, rather than in the `ON`.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a noticeable difference between the two queries. Nevertheless, I would recommend using the query with the where clause. Having that on a separate line makes your query easier to read, and if you needed to rewrite it, it'll be easier for you or others to find the WHERE clause and fix it.

Here is some additional reading material for you: [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)